# Why slicing on two similar DataFrames working differently?

Tags: python, pandas

I understand slicing on Pandas DataFrames returns rows as DataFrame and should return empty DataFrame if no row is selected.

My question is regarding the discrepancy between the two examples I am trying in Pandas 1.2.0

The first on results empty dataframe (as I was expecting):

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4 * 4).reshape(4, 4),  
                     index=['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4'], 
                     columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'])
>> df['c2': 'c3']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [c1, c2, c3, c4]
Index: []
```

But the second one (picked from ["Python for Data Analysis, 2nd Edition"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781491957653/)) throw KeyError!

```
>> data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4 * 4).reshape(4, 4),
                       index=['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York'],
                       columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
>> try:
...:     data['two': 'three']
...: except KeyError as k:
...:     print(f"KeyError: {k}")
...: 
KeyError: 'two'
```

My question is why the key exception for the second data frame? Why two different behavior? Am I missing something or there is bug in 1.2 version

I verified by example multiple times, I hope there is no typo. Attaching

[image]

Comment: slicing should be on the rows, especially if only brackets are used, as in this case. I beleve it shold throw an error in both cases. Not sure why the first one doesnt fail though

Comment: I did it on rows, it is just that I using labels those does not exists in row-labels -- I was expecting empty data frames for both (I don't think it should throw error)

Comment: left an answer(deleted though), hopefully it points you in the right direction

Comment: @sammywemmy, Thanks for your answer Sammy. Yes, I understand `.loc` and `.iloc` and I also understand direct slicing on dataframe done using row-labels. Actually, this example is to demonstrate that slicing does not use column indexing directly! But there is some discrepancy that either I do not understand or probably a bug in implementation

Comment: yea, I think there is a bug in the implementation. I'd suggest you raise it on pandas' github issues

Comment: That's some weird stuff.  Note that, if you change your first example to use nonsense names (`df['what':'who'}`), you get the exact same result.  Why does the first one work (returning nothing) and the second doesn't?

Comment: Ya, I just notice [Pandas released 1.3 in July 2021](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/index.html)  I will give it a try before to log a bug.

Comment: @TimRoberts still `df['what':'who']` returns an empty dataframe while `data['what':'who']` throw an exception

Comment: Yep, and ThePyGuy explains that the difference is because I happened to pick two names in alphabetical order.  That's the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

pandas throws **KeyError** for row slicing if the row indices are not sorted, and one of the the two indices is missing.

---

Looking at documentation for [slicing with labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-with-labels), pandas clearly mentions that it will throw a **KeyError**

> However, if at least one of the two is absent and the index is not
> sorted, an error will be raised (since doing otherwise would be
> computationally expensive, as well as potentially ambiguous for mixed
> type indexes)

When you are doing `df['c1':'c2']` and `data['two': 'three']`, you are observing two different behaviors because of the index values for rows.

In the first case i.e. `df`, the indices are sorted so no **KeyError** is thrown, in the second case index values are not sorted so it throws **keyError**, and error will not be thrown if you try the same thing after sorting the index.

```py
>>> data.sort_index()['one':'two']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [one, two, three, four]
Index: []
```

In both of the above examples, pandas will look for the values in the row indices not the column indices, and that is why it will return an empty dataframe even if the values exist in the column index:

```py
>>> df['c1':'c4']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [c1, c2, c3, c4]
Index: []
```

You might be curious why above results in empty dataframe instead of throwing **keyError** again since neither of `c1` and `c4` exist in the row index. That is actually the native python behavior which doesn't throw any `IndexError` for slicing, try:

```py
>>> [][100:200]
[]
```

And since the row indices are not sorted in the second case, pandas will throw **KeyError**, because pandas is not actually looking at those values at column indices, but the row index values.

Comment: I see what you are saying, and it fits the observations, but I do not see how a reasonable person could conceivably have intuited that from the documentation.

Comment: I want to emphasize that you are RIGHT, but the behavior still isn't sensible.  In the `df['c1':'c4']` case, those names aren't in the row list either, even though they happen to be in alphabetical order.  I would argue that should get a KeyError as well.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I have explained that as well.